# IPv4-IPv6 Proxy

Tags: proxy, dns, vps, ipv6

Есть дешевый NAT VPS, на котором требуется разместить сайт с доступом через IPv4. Провайдер выделил IPv6 и предлагает использовать устлуги IP4->6 от Cloudflare. Домен сейчас прописан на DNS Яндекса и переносить его куда-то не хочется.

Поддерживает ли сервис от Яндекса подобный функционал (AAAA-запись Яндекс делать дает) или DNS сервер выполняет какие-то еще манипуляции и одной AAAA не достаточно и все же нужно переносить домен?

Comment: А у вас dual-stack?

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist Этот тип VPS не имеет глобального IPv4-адреса. Он получает случайную переадресацию порта с IPv4-адреса, разделяемого многими VPS.